# Tomb Raider II save file location on MacOS Monterey (Aspyr Media)

Tags: applications, filesystem, games

I used to use MacOS Mojave, and used the Aspyr Media version "Tomb Raider II" on the App Store. This game no longer works in later versions of Mac, so I dual boot Mojave and run it there.

The problem is, how can I transfer my save files? They are located somewhere on my (now Monterey) hard drive, but I can't see them. The game is also there, but can't run. If I could find them, I could transfer them into the corresponding folder in Mojave on the other boot. And play from where I left off (Barkhang Monastery, about half way through the level).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found them in the hidden Library folder. So try looking for (my username is alex):

"Users/alex/Library/Application Support/Tomb Raider 2/Save/savegame.0"

See also savegame.1, savegame.2, and so on. These files will exist so long as you have saved a game within Tomb Raider II. The folder will exist either way.

In detail, show hidden files with Apple+Shift+. (...that is, the period key .). Then, open the now visible Library folder. After much manual searching, finally I found them in "Application Support" then "Tomb Raider 2" then "Save", which contains files like "savegame.0" and "savegame.1" (if you created these by saving games within Tomb Raider 2).

**This differs from the Aspyr support guide** [here](https://support.aspyr.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056571831-How-to-find-my-Save-Files-and-Game-Folder), which suggests "~/Users/alex/Library/Containers...." then looking for something like "com.aspyr.TombRaider2.appstore", which I could not find on my version of MacOS Mojave.